What is the meaning of frame-src 'self' blob:?
I want to restrict my site to blob: only from its own origin.
I thought frame-src 'self' blob: would do that but checking on  checked on CSP evaluator the results are:

It shows 'self' & blob.
What is the precise meaning here, is that allowing all blob from all sites ? If yes how can I restrict it to only blobs from the same origin?
